# Why does the computational time of maximum likelihood estimators depend only on the number of UNIQUE observations?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, least-squares, bootstrap, m-estimation

The following paper says that the computational time of least squares, maximum likelihood, and M-estimators in general depend only on the number of **UNIQUE** observations.

Intuitively it makes sense to me, but I don't know if my justification is correct. Here is what I think in the case of *maximum likelihood*:

Suppose we observe $x_1, ..., x_{10} \sim P(\theta)$. 
Then if the 10 observations are unique, the log-likelihood is $$\log L(\theta|x_1) + ... + \log L(\theta|x_{10}).$$ 
However, if all 10 observations are the same, then the log-likelihood is simply $$10 \times \log L(\theta|x_1),$$
which is cheaper to compute. Thus the computational time of MLE only depends on the number of **unique** observations.

For *least squares*, I think the statement follows from using the weighted least squares where the weight for observation $i$ is set to the number of times it is duplicated.

Source:

Kleiner, Ariel, Ameet Talwalkar, Purnamrita Sarkar, and Michael I. Jordan. "A scalable bootstrap for massive data." Journal of the Royal Statistical Society: Series B (Statistical Methodology) 76, no. 4 (2014): 795-816.

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.698.1695&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Your analysis is fine.  What is your question?

Comment: @whuber Thank you. I didn't know if my justification for the paper's claim is correct, so I wanted to cross validate it.